# How can I get previous HTTP url or hash based on Backbone.js solutions?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My use-case

1 User opens page '#place/1235' 
2 User clicks on image and system changes hash on '#popup/i135' and shows popup 
3 User closes popup 
4 I need to change url to previous one ('/place/1235')

How can I do it based on [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) (history, router) ?

Comment: Why do you change the hash when the user clicks on the pop up? W not just pass replace:true and then launch the popup and then when the pop up closes they're still at the same URL as before

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are using the URL to change views (or in this case, launch a sub-view).

There's no need when opening pop-ups to give a new URL, just set the view appropriately.

*Related reading:*

[Stop Using Backbone As If It Were A Stateless Web Server](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/03/stop-using-backbone-as-if-it-were-a-stateless-web-server/)

Comment: I agree with the examples provided in the link you gave. (deleting a model based on a route). However a popup is a different story. On mobile many users expect the back button to function when a popup appears. For example facebook does the same (by using a get parameter). Related reading: http://baymard.com/blog/back-button-expectations?utm_source=Blog+posts&utm_campaign=1068362bdd-mailchimp&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_b4e65c1647-1068362bdd-374213582

Comment: That's a fair point, and perhaps (thinking off the top of my head) you could nest the popup in the route: something like `#place/1234/popup/blah` or `#place/1234?popup=blah`. That way, when a popup closes, you can easily derive the original route from the popup route.